# pandas equivalent functions for postgresql

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and can you point me how i can implement the following sql in python pandas? Much appreciated...

scenario: For each Name grouped by sign, if the MoveStatus is 'engine', fill in any missing or zero speeds with the average of all speeds for that sign

```
with cte as (       
    select Name, sign,speed
    from tableA 
    where MoveStatus='engine' and (speed = 0.0 or speed is null)
    group by Name, sign,speed
    order by 3
    ),
    cte1 as (
    select sign,avg(speed) as speed from tableA 
    where MoveStatus='engine'  group by sign 
    ),
    cte2 as (
    select c.sign as signcte2 ,c1.speed as speedcte2
    from cte c left join cte1 c1 using (sign)
    )
update 
    tableA as r 
set 
    speed=case when (r.speed = 0.0 or r.speed is null) then c.speedcte2 else r.speed end 
from 
    cte2 as c 
where r.sign = c.signcte2 and r.MoveStatus='engine'
```

Comment: Quick remark: Please denote which are your tables...

Comment: Hi @ Yannis P., tableA is the main table i want to update based on the cte* tables

Comment: @ Yannis P.: updated the scenario